# How do I solve a system of linear equations using SageMath?

Tags: sage, linear-equation

I have system of linear equations, however I DO NOT want the answer to be a number - I want it in terms of the parameters.

ax+by= m
cx+dy= n
 I don't have the values for any of the constants, so I for the above equation, I'd just want the answer x = (md-nb)/(ad-bc) and y = (mc-na)/(bc-ad).

How do I do this in Sage?

Answer (score 6):

```
var('a b c d m n x y')
solve([a*x+b*y==m,c*x+d*y==n],x,y)
```

Comment: Live example: http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwrSyzSUE9USFJIVkhRyFXIU6hQqFTX5OUqzs8pS9WITtSq0E7SqrS1zdVJBjJTQMy8WJ0KnUpNAPAaERY=&lang=sage